# How to add and delete row in subgrid of angular?

Tags: angularjs

How to add and delete row in subgrid of angular?

Expandable grid.ng click is not working in subgrid cell template.

Please guide me, I am using angular UI grid.appScope and it's not working for me.

expandableRowTemplate:

```
<div ui-grid="row.entity.subGridOptions" external-scopes="row.entity.subGridOptions.externalScope" style="height:126px;"></div>
```

In subGridOption am using externalScope:

```
$scope.myViewModel
```

in cell Template:

```
ng-click="getExternalScopes().delete1()
```

the function is

```
$scope.myViewModel = { delete1: function () { alert("test"); } };
```

Comment: expandableRowTemplate:'<div ui-grid="row.entity.subGridOptions" external-scopes="row.entity.subGridOptions.externalScope"  style="height:126px;"></div>'

Comment: In subGridOption am using externalScope: $scope.myViewModel,in cell Template ng-click="getExternalScopes().delete1()",the function is     $scope.myViewModel = {
                delete1: function () {
                    alert("test");
                }
            };